# Workflow for porting new features from a derivative fork

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fork, git-workflow

I have repos for `project1` and `project2`. `project2` was forked from `project1` with no intention of merging it back (it's now a separate product).

Now, I have introduced some features in `project2` that I want to selectively port back to `project1`. Should I add `project2`'s repo as a remote to `project1` and do `git cherry-pick`? Or should I use `git format-patch` followed by `git am`?

The features in question are quite complex are have been implemented over a number of commits after the projects have diverged.